# Dificuldade com mysqli_fetch_object

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou realizando a função da seguinte forma:

Através de uma query:

```
<?php
[...]
$sql = 
"SELECT f_u.*, f_i.*, f_g.* FROM form_user AS f_u 
LEFT JOIN form_imovel AS f_i ON f_i.imovel_id = $imovel_id 
LEFT JOIN form_img AS f_g ON f_g.imovel_id = $imovel_id WHERE f_u.user_id = 
$user_id"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row_cont = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $row_cont;
while($rowb = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
{    echo '$rowb->file_name';
} 
?>
```

Mas na saída obtenho a contagem das linha(`$row_cont=3`), mas o resultado do `while` retorna apenas 2 resultados.

**Edit**
Essa query é feita em 3 tabelas onde form_user e form_imovel eu tenho apenas 1 registro e na tabela form_img 3 com os mesmo `id` do `imovel_id`.

```
form_user  | form_imovel       | form_img
----------   ------------------  -----------------------
user_id      user_id| imovel_id  imovel_id|file_name
77           77       7          7         seven.jpg
                                 7         seven7.jpg
                                 7         seven77.jpg
```

Comment: Faça um teste utilizando o `mysqli_fetch_all()`, para verificar se vem todos os itens.

Comment: descobri onde tá o erro vou editar a questão...

Comment: Se conseguiu resolver o problema posta a resposta, e depois defina ela como correta.